# R plotting without text

Tags: r, plot, fonts, r-markdown, manjaro

Recently, after a change of OS, my R started giving some trouble when I used commands like plot() and ggplot(). Whenever I call such plots it renders a plot like in the image, with all the textual information as small squares.

```r
    plot(cars)
```

[image: plot(cars) without text]

If before calling the plot() function I call par(family="") with a known font, I do get the expected output.

```r
    par(family = "Noto Mono")
    plot(cars)
```

[image: plot(cars) with text after par(family="Noto Mono")]

Nevertheless, if I am writing a Rmarkdown file, I must include par(family="") in each and every chunk, otherwise the error continues.

The results of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Manjaro Linux
Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pt_BR.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pt_BR.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2
```

It seems like it is a problem with the system fonts available system-wide, but I have already installed the packages with adobe and MS fonts in my Manjaro, with no success. Is there anyway to set the font family session/document-wide? Does anybody had this problem before and knows a workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should give some more details:  what OS did you change to?  What R version are you using?  Adding the result of `sessionInfo()` will probably give all these details.

Comment: Just added the sessionInfo(). I just installed a fresh version of Manjaro in my new drive. I booted the previous drive which I'm keeping as a backup and the problem does not take place there.

Comment: What is your default graphics device on that system?  If it is `X11()`, then you can change the default font using the `X11.options()` function.